# how to pass param to js for custom page in drupal 8 ?

Tags: 8

I want to pass variable to js for my custom page. Tried below code which is working fine with static value. But I m not able do same thing with existing variable of custom template.

```
    function test_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
        return [
            'test_template' => [
                'variables' => [
                    'nDetails' => null
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

 function test_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
        print_r($variables['nDetails']); // its showing empty??? 
        $routeName = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
        if ($routeName == 'test.content') {
            $variables['#attached']['drupalSettings']['test']['data'] = $variables['nDetails'];
    $variables['#attached']['drupalSettings']['test']['dataa'] = "work fine";
        }
    }

class TestController extends ControllerBase {
    public function content() {
        return [
            '#theme' => 'test_template',
            '#nDetails' => "test1"
        ];
    }
```

Is something wrong with above code? Or there is another way to pass variable to drupal setting from controller itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only see the variable in the preprocess hook of the custom template `hook_preprocess_test_template()`. But you don't need a preprocess hook at all, because you can attach the drupal settings in the controller directly:

```
return [
  '#theme' => 'test_template',
  '#attached' => [
    'drupalSettings' => [
      'test' => [
        'data' => 'test1',
      ],
    ],
  ],
];
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks its work perfectly.